# Apache Pig - Is it possible to serialize a variable?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata, apache-pig

Let's take the wordCount example:

```
input_lines = LOAD '/tmp/my-copy-of-all-pages-on-internet' AS (line:chararray);

-- Extract words from each line and put them into a pig bag
-- datatype, then flatten the bag to get one word on each row
bag_words = FOREACH input_lines GENERATE FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(line)) AS word;
```

Is it possible to serialize the "bag_words" variable so that we don't have to rebuild the entire bag each time we want to execute the script ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you just write bag_words to a file and then read it in later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`STORE bag_words INTO 'some-output-directory';`

Then read it in later to skip the foreach generate, flatten, tokenize.

Comment: Remark: store outputs to a `directory` (if it doesn't exist).

Comment: Good idea. But what should I use next to load it ?

Comment: @shanks_roux `reloaded = load '/path/to/dir' as (word:chararray);`

Comment: are you sure about the "word:charrarray" ? If i do that, it won't be possible to iterate over the bag tuples.

Comment: @shanks_roux You can leave the `AS (word:chararray)` clause off, but you'll have to reference the fields by number if you want to specify them (using Pig positional notation: $0, $1, $2, etc..) - but then you're losing the structure you created, which references the entire line as 'word'.

Comment: Exactly. Is there a way to avoid this problem ?

Comment: Well, if you want to treat each line as "word" then use `AS (word:chararray)`.  I guess I'm not sure what you mean, because after your FOREACH/GENERATE, you end up with a bag that contains tuples identified by "word", which is exactly what you'd get with Lorand Bendig's LOAD above.

Answer (score 0):

You can output any alias in pig using the STORE command: you could use standard formats (like CSV) or write your own PigLoader class to implement any specific behaviour. You can then LOAD this output in a separate script, thus bypassing the initial LOAD.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't see how i could keep the bag structure by storing and loading the variable... do you have an idea ?